# How to implement inverse log-polar transform in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, polar-coordinates

I implement the log-polar transform and its inversion. The forward transform is ok but the inversion picture shows the incorrect result. I think the issue is on the normalization of the grid coordinates. But I can't figure out how this happend.

LPT:

```py
def log_polar_transform(x, radius_factor = tf.sqrt(2.)):
    b, h, w, c = x.shape
    grid = make_grid(h, w) #(2, hw), represent log-polar coordinate system
    grid = tf.repeat(grid[None, ...], b, axis=0) #(b, 2, hw) 
    X, Y = grid[:, 0], grid[:, 1]
    
    #theta 
    theta = (Y + 1) * math.pi #[0, 2pi]
    
    #radius
    maxR = max(h, w) * radius_factor
    r = tf.exp((X + 1)/2 * tf.math.log(maxR)) #[1, h]
    r = (r-1)/(maxR -1) #[0, h]-->[0, 1]
    r = r * (maxR/h) #scale factorize
    
    #map to cartesian coordinate system
    xs = tf.reshape(r * tf.math.cos(theta), [b, h, w])
    ys = tf.reshape(r * tf.math.sin(theta), [b, h, w])
    output = interpolate(x, xs, ys)
    output = tf.reshape(output, [b, h, w, c])
    return output
```

Inverse LPT:

```py
def inverse_log_polar_transform(x):
    b, h, w, c = x.shape
    grid = make_grid(h, w) 
    grid = tf.repeat(grid[None, ...], b, axis=0) #(b, 2, hw) 
    X, Y = grid[:, 0], grid[:, 1]
    rs = tf.sqrt(X**2 + Y **2)/tf.sqrt(2.)
    ts = (tf.atan2(-Y, -X))/math.pi #[-1., 1.]
    
    rs = tf.reshape(rs, [b, h, w])
    ts = tf.reshape(ts, [b, h, w])
    output = interpolate(x, rs, ts)
    output = tf.reshape(output, [b, h, w, c])
    return output
```

Here is the full code link:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/tom99763/log-polar-transfomr-inverse

and the reusults:

[Results Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24vCq.png)

Comment: Please post a minimal version. Just doing the math should be the first step. Does converting a single cartesian coordinate (x,y) to log-polar and then back using your formulas gives you the expected result?

Comment: rs = tf.sqrt(X**2 + Y **2)/tf.sqrt(2.)  @VPfB This term should take log according to the formula of log-polar coordinate. But it gives a large black hole if the value of rs is under 1.